# Can't get Atlassian Connect Express to Install

Tags: node.js, npm, confluence, atlassian-connect

I am trying to install Atlassian Connect Express (ACE) following these instructions:

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/getting-started/#install-ace

It throws this error when I reach the `npm install` step:

```
node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.4/node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.4/node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.4/node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.4 and node@9.4.0 (node-v59 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.4/node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp verb command build [ 'rebuild' ]
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3090100/sqlite3.c
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/deps/action_before_build.stamp
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3090100/sqlite3.o
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3090100/sqlite3.c:9704:26: warning: unused variable 'sqlite3one' [-Wunused-const-variable]
SQLITE_PRIVATE const int sqlite3one = 1;
                         ^
^Cmake: *** [Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3090100/sqlite3.o] Interrupt: 2
```

What should I do to get **ACE** to install properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by any chance running NodeJS version 9? I've recently started working with the ACE library as well and found out that one of it's dependencies, sqlite, doesn't install under this major version of NodeJS. As a workaround for now I suggest you switch back to NodeJS version 8 until this gets fixed. Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect, this worked.  I ended up using nvm so the versions of node don't get messy.  But it's able to install sqlite now, thank you!